# Problem With Azure CDN Cache configuration

Tags: azure, cdn, cache-control, azure-appservice, azure-cdn

I'm trying to create an azure CDN for azure app service to get a better perfomance, however I need ensure to the final user that the latest version of my blazor web app is not displayed in the browser, for this I set up the Rules Engine for the CDN of different ways but when I deploy the service, I need delete the browser cache or I can not see the latest version.

I made several configurations but nothing works fine, currently I have the next configuration according to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-how-caching-works):

[image: Azure CDN Global configuration]

Aditional I ran the next command after deployment to purge the cdn content but it doesn't works too

```
az cdn endpoint purge -g resource-group-name -n cdnName --profile-name ProfileCDNName --content-paths '/*'
```

Which Configuration should work to ensure that the cdn display the current version of the blazor app?

Comment: Can you try using bypass cache in cache behavior like [this](https://i.imgur.com/iEfWb5v.png)

Comment: I solved the problem using bypass cache in the rules engine and added a task to purge cdn inside a release pipeline after succesfull deployments